# Scraping a website with multiple alphabetical tabs containing multiple pages

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping a website which has data listed alphabetically within A-Z tabs and each alphabet tab further contains several pages. How do i extract all the URLs from this?

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
String keyword = "a";
String url = "http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/brand-index.asp?alpha=" + keyword; 

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
//Elements pages = doc.select("div.pagination a"); 
Element table = doc.select("table").get(1);

for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
    for (Element tds : row.select("td")) {
        Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out how to scrape data from each alphabetical tab and each page within each alphabet tab. Below is the code. However, after scraping a few hundred links I get a read time out error. Is there an efficient way to do this? Can I apply multithreading to this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final int OK = 200;
        String currentURL;
        int page = 1;
        int status = OK;
        Connection.Response response = null;
        Document doc = null;
        String[] keywords = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        //String keyword = "a";
        for (String keyword : keywords){
            final String url = "https://www.medindia.net/drug-price/brand-index.asp?alpha="+keyword; 
            while (status == OK) {
                currentURL = url +"&page="+ String.valueOf(page); 
                response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                        .execute();
                status = response.statusCode();


                if (status == OK) {
                    doc = response.parse();

                    Element table = doc.select("table").get(1);

                    for (Element rows : table.select("tr")) {
                        for (Element tds : rows.select("td")) {
                            Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
                            for (Element link : links) {
                                System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
                                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                page++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think what are you doing right now might from a webserver point of view might look like DDoS attack. Be careful when crawling webpages, because you might be blocked completely.  Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Crawling_policy